# Meteor: Get url of uploaded image in CollectionFS photo-blog example

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I'd like to be able to pass the URL of an uploaded image in javascript in the tutorial example [making a photoblog in meteor](http://experimentsinmeteor.com/photo-blog-part-1/).

In that example (in home.js), the helper for templates that render images returns Images.find(), which is used in the image template (image.html) to output html to show the image via:

`<img src="{{url}}" />`

This works fine, as does the entire tutorial, including S3.  However, I'd like to combine it with another project, and that one will require storing and passing around the url under program control.

It would seem that because the template is able to use {{url}}, that in js, one could, in the simplest case, use Images.findOne().url to get at least the first url. E.g., I have modified the given helper to contain this:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  'images': function() {
   console.log("url from home helper:  = "  + Images.findOne().url);  //cannot read url property
   return Images.find();
   }
 });
```

However, this gets the error "cannot read url property..." (and after that, for some reason, the console prints out a huge batch of source code!!) If the template is able to render the field "url" from the collection image object, why can't js see it?

How can I get at the url in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the url is the function not the property so you have to use `Images.findOne().url()` not the `Images.findOne().url`

or

if you are getting the same error that because your findone method return undefined.
There are the possible issues.

1. Your Images collection are empty.
2. You did not publish then images and not subscribe the images.
3. You may be using this call before uploading the images.

I hope this this may solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj...but I know none of those 3 possibilities are happening because I also put a findOne().url in dropzone.js, where a new image is uploaded and tried it after loading (and displaying) several images.  There's publish and subscribe in publications.js and home.js.  I was able to get to the urls from the DOM when clicking on an image, so I know the urls are working and available, but when they're stored or displayed in javascript.  I have a theory that maybe I need to specify the store in my findOne statement?  Or some other magic things that CollecitonFS does?  THANKS!

Comment: I should note that I am using the exact code of the photo-blog tutorial and all else works as expected.  The only statements I've added are console.log statements containing findone's, which fail.  I later added event processing for getting urls from clicking on images.

Comment: Images.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    download: function () {
        return true;
    }
});
Please match these three are there or not.

Comment: Please check also the images are storing or not in the folder and check the permission as well.

Comment: Please also check it as well https://github.com/PankajJatav/meteor-image-upload-demo

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Those allow statements are in the photo-blog code in images.js.  All images are storing correctly and are available.  I tried your github demo and it is a great slimmed down proof of concept and works for me.  However, it doesn't store urls for the uploaded object which can then be rendered in a template, does it?  That's my problem with photo-blog. It is storing urls with each file object, and using them for rendering a template, but I can't access them from javascript.

Comment: I just check that you used Images.findOne().url So I update my answer.